# Page blank in PDDocument after split

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to create a `PDDocument` and then add two pages to it.
The first one containing the text "first page" and the second one being blank.
I then split the `PDDocument` and put it into a list.
When I try to access the first page (by using the get Method), I save it expecting to see a pdf with the text "first page" on it but all I get it a blank page.
Any suggestions?

```
package split;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Splitter;

public class pdfSplit {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PDPage page1, page2;

        page1 = new PDPage();
        page2 = new PDPage();

        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

        document.addPage(page1);
        document.addPage(page2);

        List<PDDocument> splittedPDF =  splitter.split(document);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page1);

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont( font, 50 );
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
        contentStream.drawString( "First page" );
        contentStream.endText();

        contentStream.close();



        document = splittedPDF.get(0);      //No effect
        document.save("Random.pdf");
    }

}
```

Comment: If I do that then the program has nothing to split so when I get to the splittedPDF.get(0), it will give an IndexOutOfBounds error

Comment: Nope, it gives the same result. A BLANK PDF.

Comment: I checked the API, it looks like there is another `PDPageContentStream` constructor you can use. One with a boolean which indicates whether or not you'd like to overwrite the page source: `public PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage, boolean appendContent, boolean compress)`

Check here for the API source: https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is blank because you do the split before writing to the page content stream. Solution: move the splitting code to after closing your content stream. Correct code thus looks like this:

```
    PDPage page1, page2;

    page1 = new PDPage();
    page2 = new PDPage();

    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    document.addPage(page1);
    document.addPage(page2);

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page1);

    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 50);
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
    contentStream.drawString("First page");
    contentStream.endText();

    contentStream.close();
    // now the page is filled!


    List<PDDocument> splittedPDF = splitter.split(document);

    document = splittedPDF.get(0);
    document.save("Random.pdf");
```

(This answer was done with version 1.8.10)